# Click event on element

Tags: svg, jointjs

How to find out which element is clicked in jointjs. I want to create a clone of element which is double clicked.

I tried this:

```
paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
                    var rect = new joint.shapes.devs.Model({
                        position: {x: 100, y: 50},
                        size: {width: 51, height: 41},
                        outPorts: [''],
                        attrs: {
                            '.label': {text: '', 'ref-x': .4, 'ref-y': .2},
                            rect: {fill: 'white'},
                            '.outPorts circle': {fill: 'white', stroke: 'black'},
                            '.port-body': {r: 5}
                        }
                    });
                    graph.addCell(rect);
                });
```

But the above creates a clone when double clicked on any of the element on paper.

Answer (score 1):

The clicked `element` is retrievable via `cellView` in the `model`attribute.

Here's a sample of what you are trying to do :

```
  paper.on('cell:pointerdblclick', function (cellView, evt, x, y) {
    //clone cell and add it to graph
    graph.addCell(cellView.model.clone());
  });
```

Via `cellView.model` you can check which `element` is clicked by checking its properties via [prop](http://jointjs.com/api#joint.dia.Element:prop) and decide if you clone the `element`.